# jquery mobile data-native-menu in dynamically generated select from jeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

Hello at all the instruction `data-native-menu="false"` work correctly if I put directly in select but if I put this code in a select generated by javascript(using Jeditabple plugin) it don't work.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/frizzo28/pytv69fm/14/
How you can see the "menu" of select with test1,test2 etc work perfectly. But the other select(click on "Click here" to show) no.

Any suggestion?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I used the jquery mobile selectmenu refresh in this way:

```
,
    plugin : function(settings, original) {
         $("#datimod").selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);
}
```

Here the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/frizzo28/pytv69fm/15/